# Error in cloudwatch logs while attempting to indexing data in an Amazon ES cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm following [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/compute/indexing-amazon-dynamodb-content-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-using-aws-lambda/) to automatically index all my DynamoDB streams into the Amazon ElasticSearch service cluster that I created .

I followed it step by step and I created all permissions policies.

However, when I am testing, nothing is indexed in my Amazon ES cluster. When I check CloudWatch, I see this log:

```
('ERROR: ', 'Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 123, in lambda_handler
 return _lambda_handler(event, context)
 File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 219, in _lambda_handler
 post_to_es(es_payload) # post to ES with exponential backoff
 File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 86, in post_to_es
 es_ret_str = post_data_to_es(payload, es_region, creds, es_endpoint, \'/_bulk\')
 File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 53, in post_data_to_es
 req = botocore.awsrequest.create_request_object(params)
 File "/var/runtime/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 314, in create_request_object
 request_object.context.update(r[\'context\'])
KeyError: \'context\'
')
```

I don't understand the issue. All I know is my Lambda function successfully trigger each DynamoDB streams and can send logs to CloudWatch, but cannot index these data in Amazon ES.

Someone please can help me to solve this issue?

Comment: well the error is self explanatory, your `r` dict does not have `context` key

Answer (score 0):

There was a recent breaking change in botocore code being used by aws lambda.

The effected line of code is:
`req = botocore.awsrequest.create_request_object(params)`

With new changes, they are expecting argument *params* to contain 'context' field.

So please add context field to your params argument:
Example: `params = {'method': method, 'url': proto + host + path, 'region': region, 'headers': {'Host': host}, 'body': payload,'context': {'signing': {'region': 'us-east-1'}}}`

Once you make above changes, your lambda should be able to run successfully.

Details:
In the file botocore.awsrequest, the code change at line 314 is causing this issue.
https://github.com/boto/botocore/commit/28b8831f5f8518bef5accf994fc377c58a3569f7#diff-cb00fc815f8f80ae15e7d0cecc74b395